# How do I tell what sort of solder I have?

Tags: soldering

My soldering iron came as part of a kit and I have really not used it very much at all in all the years I have had it. (Read zero meaningful uses). I cannot remember who gave it to me or why. The kit came with some solder but I have since learned that there are different types including leaded and lead free. Is there a way of figuring out what type I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not labeled you can't determine its makeup easily. The answer depends on why you want to know though. It probably doesn't matter if you're doing this for hobbyist things and not commercial.

For example, lead-based solders will melt at lower temperatures than lead-free versions and are recommended for hobbyists because it's easier to work with. In a professional environment most products have to be made with lead-free solder though.

If you're just soldering for a hobby side project don't worry about it. If you have trouble getting the solder to flow than purchase some leaded solder and it should be easier.

Edit:

If you're just strictly trying to determine whether or not it is lead-based or lead-free than you can use its shininess as a good guess. Lead-free tends to be shinier than leaded. If you want to know the exact makeup percentages like Sn vs. Cu vs. Ag then the chemistry exchange might be a better place.

Comment: If he's had it for years it's likely lead based solder.  Once you get used to seeing leaded solder vs. unleaded you can tell just by looking at it.  Lead based solder is duller, lead-free is more shiny and stiffer. (In general.)

Comment: I agree in general that lead based is duller but I have a spool of lead free at my bench that is three years old and looks just as dull. Stiffness seems to depend on makeup as well as thickness. I have some 10 mil lead-free which feels soft and flimsy like leaded.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in ACD's answer - if going for a hobbyist use, don't worry too much. If the solder is melting with your soldering iron and is wetting your components and boards properly, you're fine. (Always assuming it is a solder for electronics and not for plumbing...)

If your soldering iron is temperature controlled you could try to figure out whether it is a lead-free or lead-based solder. Sn63PbAg, the most common lead-based solder melts at 178°C. Lead-Tin solders with different composition are also in the range of 180°C melting temperature. Lead-free solders, such as Tin-Copper, Tin-Silver-Copper, Tin-Silver are melting at about 220°C. So the melting point could be some indication. Be aware however that the temperature setting of the soldering iron has to be higher then those mentioned values (as much as +30..+50°C above).